# Development of the Coq library. (Add LoadPath solution is not good enough.)

Tags: coq, coqide

I am adding some theorems to the library
https://github.com/coq-contribs/zfc

But there is a not very good thing.
While I developing the code in the CoqIDE I have to add

```
Add LoadPath "/home/user/0my/GITHUB/".
```

and to rename all

```
Require Import Axioms.
```

to

```
Require Import ZFC.Axioms.
```

. All files of the library are in

```
/home/user/0my/GITHUB/ZFC
```

and the name of the last folder matters.

But when I want to run the "make" command I have to rename everything back.

The file "Make" contains the names of files and the prefix. Deleting the first line didn't solve the problem.

I don't think that it is the best practice of the developing with the CoqIDE, so what shall I do instead?

**Edited1:**

I have "run_coqide.sh" which consist of

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
COQPATH=/home/user/0my/GITHUB/ 
/home/user/opam-coq.8.8.1/4.02.3/bin/coqide
```

"From ZFC Require Import Sets. " raises error "Cannot find a physical path".

**Edited2:**

I have find out that this is a working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export COQPATH=/home/user/0my/GITHUB/ 
/home/user/opam-coq.8.8.1/4.02.3/bin/coqide
```

Is it normal run or a hack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename `Make` to `_CoqProject`, this is the name currently recognized by CoqIDE where it will look for project configuration (in particular the `-R . ZFC` option to make the Coq files in the directory visible to CoqIDE). 
It is also possible to change the name CoqIDE is looking for to `Make`, but `_CoqProject` seems to really be the new standard.

Note that the `-R . ZFC` option, that allows you to import libraries unqualified, corresponds to the command [`Add Rec LoadPath "/.../ZFC" as ZFC`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.add-rec-loadpath).

I would also suggest to actually switch the whole codebase to explicit qualification `ZFC.Axiom`, that you've been doing locally by hand, making it less error prone to work with different projects at the same time. I'm not sure why it was necessary to rename things back to run `make`, my understanding is that it shouldn't be necessary.

See also the Coq reference manual, [about the `coq_makefile` utility](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/practical-tools/utilities.html#building-a-coq-project-with-coq-makefile).

Comment: The main reason to rename back was that repository coq-contribs/zfc is not mine. I want to contribute locally without changing the whole architecture. I also edited a question by adding "export" is it right solution?

Comment: That should mostly work but it is a rather fragile approach. In particular it will be confusing if you also install packages (installations via `opam` probably won't go into the  `GITHUB` directory). What I described is my understanding of the current best practice with Coq projects, so it should be okay to update the ZFC library to follow them. Feel free to open an issue on github to ask the maintainers' opinions on the best way to approach this.